# Python quantlib examples?

Tags: python, quantlib

Does anyone know of any good quantlib examples for Python? I cant seem to find any anywhere...

Comment: http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/quantlib-python-tutorials-with-examples.html has a few good examples I wrote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are examples in the [Ubuntu package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/i386/quantlib-python/filelist) `quantlib-python`:

```
/usr/share/doc/quantlib-python/examples/american-option.py
/usr/share/doc/quantlib-python/examples/basket-option.py
/usr/share/doc/quantlib-python/examples/bermudan-swaption.py.gz
/usr/share/doc/quantlib-python/examples/european-option.py
/usr/share/doc/quantlib-python/examples/swap.py.gz
/usr/share/doc/quantlib-python/examples/test/QuantLibTestSuite.py
/usr/share/doc/quantlib-python/examples/test/bonds.py.gz
/usr/share/doc/quantlib-python/examples/test/date.py
/usr/share/doc/quantlib-python/examples/test/instruments.py
/usr/share/doc/quantlib-python/examples/test/integrals.py
/usr/share/doc/quantlib-python/examples/test/marketelements.py
/usr/share/doc/quantlib-python/examples/test/ratehelpers.py
/usr/share/doc/quantlib-python/examples/test/solvers1d.py
/usr/share/doc/quantlib-python/examples/test/termstructures.py.gz
```

If you are not using Ubuntu/Debian, there might be a similar package for your OS, or you can also get these files by downloading [quantlib-swig_0.9.9.orig.tar.gz](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/quantlib-swig/quantlib-swig_0.9.9.orig.tar.gz).

Answer (score 6):

They're in the QuantLib-SWIG distribution (you probably got that from the QuantLib site already.)  Once you unpack the tarball (or the zip archive) they're in the Python\examples folder.

Comment: omg! is it Luigi Ballabio of quantlib fame ?!

Answer (score 0):

The best (only ...) QL/Python example codes I have found so far are those written by Tawanda Gwena at https://sites.google.com/site/tgwena/engineering-docs/engineering-permissions-list